# How to match a specific number range with a regex using grep only

Tags: regex, unix, grep

For example I have a  time range below:

```
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
19
20
21
22
23
24
25
26
```

And what I want is to get the numbers from 13 to 20 only using grep -E '[1-2][??]'
is it possible?

please dont give answer about awk I'm not asking about it thank you very much

Comment: How about `egrep '1[3-9]|20'`?

Comment: @Explosion Pills nice it solved it, but can you please explain the purpose of |? thanks man

Answer (score 5):

This should do it:

```
^(1[3-9]|20)$
```

Answer (score 5):

`|` means alternation in regular expressions.  You can think of this like a logical `or`.  Thus:

```
1[3-9]|20
```

means

> 1 followed by 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, or 9, **OR** 2 followed by 0

This will match any of the numbers indicated (13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, or 20).

The above could be `1[1-9]|2[0-6]` which would be:

> 1 followed by 1 through 9 **OR** 2 followed by 0 through 6

as Bohemian indicates.  The `^` and `$` zero width assertion anchors mean "start of the string" and "end of the string" respectively.  Their exact meaning can vary depending on the regex flavor, but in `egrep` and other line-based regex flavors that is what they mean.  You would want to use these if there is the possibility of other characters in the line as in

```
a13b
&20-
```

If you know that the number will be all that is on that particular line, they are not strictly necessary.

Comment: The anchors should be used anyway because numbers can obviously have more than 2 digits and the OP didn't say anything about his numbers all being 2-digits even though that's all the input he showed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enclose the regular expression inside double quotes(" "). Besides, considering a broader search domain, if the numbers are more than 2 digits, you need to put additional quantifiers in the expression. Say you want to search for numbers in the range

```
1865259000 to 1865361999
```

your regular expression should be:

```
"1865259[0-9]{3}|18652[6-9][0-9]{4}|18653[0-6][0-1][0-9]{3}"
```

the number inside curly braces means the pattern should match exactly that number of times. so,

```
 [0-9]{2}
```

means 2 occurrences of digits between 0 to 9.